# How do I upgrade the MongoDB driver in a Kogito Quarkus project?

Tags: java, mongodb, driver, quarkus, kogito

I'm new to Kogito and Quarkus, so help me a little bit here.

Our application has been recently affected by this bug:

> https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/JAVA-4018

Now I want to upgrade the Mongo DB driver version to use the version with the fix but I'm not sure where do I need to do that.

I see these two in the pom.xml:

```
<project>
  ...
  <dependencies>
    ...
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-mongodb-client</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.kie.kogito</groupId>
      <artifactId>kogito-addons-quarkus-persistence-mongodb</artifactId>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

But I'm not sure if I should look for the driver referenced by these dependencies and then add the version tag for any of them...

Can you point me the direction where I need to look to upgrade the driver version?

Comment: You can define a specific version of mongodb client in your xml.

Answer (score 0):

Which Kogito version are you using? The latest Kogito Quarkus version already uses the [latest MongoDB driver](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-java-driver/releases/tag/r4.7.1):

```
[INFO] ----< org.kie.kogito.examples:process-mongodb-persistence-quarkus >-----
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ process-mongodb-persistence-quarkus ---
[INFO] org.kie.kogito.examples:process-mongodb-persistence-quarkus:jar:2.0.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- org.kie.kogito:kogito-addons-quarkus-persistence-mongodb:jar:2.0.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.kie.kogito:kogito-addons-persistence-mongodb:jar:2.0.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  \- io.quarkus:quarkus-mongodb-client:jar:2.13.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.mongodb:mongodb-driver-sync:jar:4.7.1:compile
[INFO] |     |  +- org.mongodb:bson:jar:4.7.1:compile
[INFO] |     |  \- org.mongodb:mongodb-driver-core:jar:4.7.1:compile
[INFO] |     |     \- org.mongodb:bson-record-codec:jar:4.7.1:runtime
[INFO] |     +- org.mongodb:mongodb-driver-reactivestreams:jar:4.7.1:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.mongodb:mongodb-crypt:jar:1.5.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.testcontainers:mongodb:jar:1.17.3:test
```

Can you try upgrading to Kogito 1.27.0.Final?

MongoDB 4.7.1 includes the [fix you're looking for](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-java-driver/commit/47fec07b36dc831bd368d63376147c4f4690ff5a).